# How to get absolute path of a file upload in React and send it to MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I'm trying to upload files to MongoDB with react, and I'm struggling to get the absolute path in order to use GridFS to store the file.

In the backend, I have a route for AddFile defined as such:

```
const addFile = async (req, res) => {
    const { path }  = req.body        //get absolute path for file
    filename = path.split('\\').pop() //extract filename from absolute path


     const uploadStream = fs.createReadStream(path).
     pipe(bucket.openUploadStream(filename)) //store the file as the filename}
     res.json({id : uploadStream.id})

 }
```

in routes, I have the route defined as such:
`router.post('/fs', addFile)`

this function takes a Json like this

```
{
    "path" : "C:\\Users\\name\\work\\files\\file.json"
}
```

and returns the MongoDB ObjectId of the file as it is inserted into the database:

```
{
    "id": "6474b6b838e87a34febe8d0b"
}
```

In the frontend, I have an upload button through which I can add multiple files, and they basically enable me to get the name of the file in the local directory where it was selected from, but not the absolute path I need in order to store the file into GridFS. Is there a better way to upload insert files into mongoDB or is there a way to get the absolute path of a file through upload?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a security restriction as MDN [writes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name):
"For security reasons, the path is excluded from this property."

Browsers don't share that information intentionally